# Set a reminder every X days before password expiration

Tags: login, password

is there any way to set a password reminder every each X days before password expiration in Y days of overall Z days?

I would need to set this offline (i.e. no change command).

For example, I would need a password policy done like this:

- Expiration time is 365 days (Z=365)

  - Starting from 30 days before expiration (Y=30)
  - I would need a reminder every 7 days for password
    change (Z=7).

Comment: Everything except for "reminder every 7 days" is done with `passwd`, see `man passwd`

Comment: Since I can't use passwd on the host machine, I would need to know the actual changes on files that passwd does instead of the actual command :)

Comment: It changes `/etc/shadow` - if you can't run `passwd` you can't change that file either.

Comment: Hi @Panki, I need to set it offline. Could you please tell me which /etc/shadow parameter does passwd change? Thank you